# How do I write a regular expression for multiple words/phrases in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

So I know how to find one word keywords just fine:

```
text =~ /keyword1|keyword2|keyword3/i
```

But how do I find phrases? E.g. "The sky is blue....but sometimes it turns to orange."

I tried doing:

```
text =~ /(the sky is blue)|(orange sky)|(sky is blue but orange)/i
```

but that didn't work.

Thoughts? Basically, how do I string together a number of keywords separated by a space and be able to find text that corresponds to those phrases?

Comment: What exactly is your expected input and desired output?

Comment: My expected input is phrases of at least 2 words to many multiples of that, of which I will want to choose those that match the specific rules of my regex (i.e. I have specific phrases I am searching for - like the ones above about the sky). The important thing is being able to look through a string of a random number of individual words (separated by a space - or even multiple spaces) and detect to see if one of the phrases in my regex appear.

Comment: Note that a) the parens are unnecessary, and b) you can generate literal regex alternation with [`Regexp.union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union): `Regexp.union("foo bar", "jim jam", "yay") #=> /foo\ bar|jim\ jam|yay/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "that didn't work". `=~` returns the index where the regex found a match:

```
"The sky is blue....but sometimes it turns to orange." =~ /(the sky is blue)|(orange sky)|(sky is blue but orange)/i
# => 0
```

`0` is the index where "the sky is blue" found its match. If no match is found `=~` returns `nil`. `0` is "truthy" and `nil` is "falsey" in Ruby, so the result of the match could be used in an `if` statement.

If those are the exact phrases you are looking for, your existing regex should work just fine.

```
"The sky is green....but sometimes it turns to orange sky." =~ /(the sky is blue)|(orange sky)|(sky is blue but orange)/i
# => 46
```

You can use the [String#squeeze](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze) method to remove multiple spaces before running your regex.

```
"The sky is green....but sky is blue      but orange sometimes.".squeeze!(" ") =~ /(the sky is blue)|(orange sky)|(sky is blue but orange)/i
# => 24
```

Does that help?

Comment: Hrmmmm....seems I may have fat-fingered this one. I had a trailing pipe `|` at the end of my regexp, so it was returning a lot of false positives. However, now it seems to be working fine. You are correct. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. See @Phrogz excellent comment for how to _improve_ your regex. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `\s` instead of space if you dont care about other whitespace characters.
But if you need to match **only** space characters you can use code of space symbol (`\u0020`):

```
text =~ /(the\u0020sky\u0020is\u0020blue)|(orange\u0020sky)|(sky\u0020is\u0020blue\u0020but\u0020orange)/i
```

Comment: So you mean something like: `text =~ /(the\ssky\sis\sblue)|(orange\ssky)/i`?

Comment: Yes if there are no tabs or new line symbols instead of spaces.

Comment: Or possibly `/the\s+sky\s+is\s+blue/` to allow for multiple whitespace characters.

Comment: What's wrong with just typing a literal space character instead of using its codepoint?